# Amplitude / Frequency analysis in Matlab

Tags: matlab, wav, analysis, frequency, spectrum

I have a 2D graph that I have created of frequency vs. amplitude as a way to characterize a signal. I am trying to figure out how to write script that takes the WAV I have already imported into MATLAB, and figure out the peaks, the troughs, and the distance between each one. Can someone please help me with some **general guidelines, not a complete code**, for a script that will help me do this?

Comment: I think you'll also find `findpeaks` quite useful (signal processing toolbox).

Comment: Are you looking for `FFT`? I.e. convert your signal from the time domain to the frequency domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several submissions on the [file exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/) for this. For instance [this one](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11755-peak-finding-and-measurement), seems applicable (I haven't tested it myself, but it looks good).

Try to search a bit on the file exchange and you will likely find something you can use.

You can also have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261122/determine-frequency-from-signal-data-in-matlab?rq=1), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253701/signal-analysis-amplitude-estimation-in-matlab?rq=1).